# Firefox doesn't return POST data after returning from Paypal site

Tags: php, firefox, paypal

I'm using `paypal IPN` on my site. After payment is done, customers return to the site and a `PHP` script will process the transaction data paypal sends within `$_POST` variable.

The data is passed ok when using any browser except **Mozilla Firefox**.
It appears to show a warning about sending data from ***https://*** site to ***http://***

If I click ok button within the next second, the warning appears so the data is passed ok.
However, when I wait a few second and then click the button `$_POST` is empty.

**Opera**, for example, shows the same warning but the post data is delivered anyway.
The problem appears in Firefox only.

Has anyone met this problem?

Comment: the IPN data has nothing to do with a browser so im confused

Answer (score 1):

Hill79, thank you very much for your response.

I have resolved the problem making the code work with auto-return and [PDT](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/) enabled. 
Now the script gets `$_GET` parameters and calls the payment data based on the PDT token.

Works like a charm now!

The reason I used the `$_POST` data before is because that was kind of old code written by another developer when there was no auto-return option provided by PayPal.

Anyway, if you have some chance try to send $_POST from a secured domain (**https://**) to non-secured one (**http://**) using **Firefox** browser. I bet you will encounter the same problem as I did: you will get the warning by the browser and after you confirm sending the data you will get nothing in `$_POST`.

Once again, thank you for your help!

Comment: I was having the same exact issue, and it was driving me crazy of course. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, you just saved my money . I was going to buy ssl certs. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Paypal's Auto-return function to send users back to your site after payment, the transaction information will be sent as URL variables ($_GET rather than $_POST).

The IPN function works independently of the users browser, Paypal sends transaction data directly back to your site (to the script you specify in your settings) via $_POST variables - the idea is that you don't have to rely on the user returning to your site in order to get the details of the transaction.

It might be wise just to double check you're not using $_POST where you should be using $_GET and that you have your Paypal settings configured correctly.